# Error get name value copy from textarea

Tags: php, jquery

```
    <script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.next').click(function(){
                $('input#productname').val($('input#_productname').val()); 
                $('textarea#description').val($('textarea#_description').val());
            }); 
        });
    </script>

    <input type="text" name="_productname" id="_productname" value="demo"/>
    <textarea name="_description" id="_description" value="demo" ></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="productname" id="productname" />
    <textarea name="description" id="description" ></textarea>
     <input id="next" class="next" type="submit" name="next" value="next" />
```

output:

```
productname = demo 
description =
```

Help me get value this tag texterea

Comment: have you tried to alert value of item

Comment: Try taking out some of the trivial code, it seems that you are putting a lot of fluff, while you really only need a few lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Textareas do not have a [value attribute <sup>documentation</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea#Attributes) (*so do not use one*).  You have to put the value between the opening and closing tag `<textarea> value here </textarea>`

and also [id's cannot start with `_` <sup>documentaion</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2) so change that too, and it should work.

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="productname_" id="productname_" value="demo"/>
<textarea name="description_" id="description_">demo</textarea>
<input type="text" name="productname" id="productname" />
<textarea name="description" id="description" ></textarea>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.next').click(function(){
            $('input#productname').val($('input#productname_').val()); 
            $('textarea#description').val($('textarea#description_').val());
        }); 
    });
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Fmxyd/

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what yo are trying to do but instead of this:

```
$('input#productname').val($('input#_productname').val()); 
$('textarea#description').val($('textarea#_description').val());
```

You should just do:

```
$('#productname').val($('#_productname').val()); 
$('#description').val($('#_description').val());
```

If you have an ID, then thats all you need.